# Can application insight key for Azure break the entire web app?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have a .NET Core (v2.2.0) Web API App deployed in Azure WebApp. The web app suddenly stopped working and gave a 502 error upon every request.

With no clue and help from logs and application insights and after hours of debugging, I found that If I remove a key

```
{
    "name": "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_PreemptSdk",
    "value": "0",
    "slotSetting": true
}
```

from the configuration of my web app, everything works again.
I tried experimenting by setting the `value` of the key from `0` to `1`, but the WebApp still doesn't work.

Does anyone have any idea about what might be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Users with similar issue have fixed the issue by installing Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore package in the .NET Core 2.2 solution. Also, add the dependency in your project/use [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore)

```
 <PackageReference
  Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector"
  Version="1.3.7" />
```

I’m not sure if this happens with both main and staging slot(s).
App Settings can be configured to sticky to slot.  You may check if - "slotSetting": false -  makes any difference.